# HTML tags in bloginfo description

Tags: php, html, description

I'm trying to set some `<span>` tags in the bloginfo description. So I put this in the blog description field:

```
<span class="name">Archive | Navarro Vives</span> <span>is a point of reference</span> <span>for those who wish to</span> <span>find out more about the life and work of Josep Navarro Vives.</span>
```

`bloginfo('description')` returns this string:

```
&lt;span class=&quot;name&quot;&gt;Archive | Navarro Vives&lt;/span&gt; &lt;span&gt;is a point of reference&lt;/span&gt; &lt;span&gt;for those who wish to&lt;/span&gt; &lt;span&gt;find out more about the life and work of Josep Navarro Vives.&lt;/span&gt;
```

And it is printed in the browser as `<span class="name">Archive | Navarro...etc` (with escaped  tags).

I tried to:

```
$description = bloginfo('description');
echo html_entity_decode($description);
```

but it returns exactly the same as bloginfo('description').

How can I unescape these `<span>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. just replace

`bloginfo('description')`

by `get_bloginfo('description')`

So

`echo html_entity_decode(get_bloginfo('description'))`

Works as expected.